# too many copy ctors i cant figure out

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class items{
    char * name;
public:
    items(const char * str){
        int len = strlen(str);
        this->name = new char [len];
        strcpy(this->name,str);
        cout << "Default ctor " << this->name << " \t@" << (this) << endl;
    }

    items(const items& obj){
        int len = strlen(obj.name);
        this->name = new char [len];
        strcpy(name,obj.name);
        cout << "Copy ctor " << this->name << " \t@" << this << endl;
    }

    ~items(){
        cout << "dtor \t" << this->name << "\t@" << this << endl;
        delete [] name;
    }

    const char * getName() const{
        return this->name;
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const items& obj){
    stream << obj.getName();
    return stream;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    items Ruler("Ruler"), Pencil("Pencil"), Book("Book"), Notebook("Notebook"), Sharpener("Sharpener");


    vector<items> school;
    school.push_back(Ruler);
    school.push_back(Pencil);
    school.push_back(Book);

    return 0;
}
```

i have bizarre results. Can you explain what is happening behind the scene?
Results:

```
Default ctor Ruler  @0x62ff1c
Default ctor Pencil     @0x62ff18
Default ctor Book   @0x62ff14
Default ctor Notebook   @0x62ff10
Default ctor Sharpener  @0x62ff0c
Copy ctor Ruler     @0x9cd1d0
Copy ctor Pencil    @0x9cd504
Copy ctor Ruler     @0x9cd500
dtor    Ruler   @0x9cd1d0
Copy ctor Book  @0x9c0510
Copy ctor Ruler     @0x9c0508
Copy ctor Pencil    @0x9c050c
dtor    Ruler   @0x9cd500
dtor    Pencil  @0x9cd504
dtor    Ruler   @0x9c0508
dtor    Pencil  @0x9c050c
dtor    Book    @0x9c0510
dtor    Sharpener   @0x62ff0c
dtor    Notebook    @0x62ff10
dtor    Book    @0x62ff14
dtor    Pencil  @0x62ff18
dtor    Ruler   @0x62ff1c
```

What is happening after default constructions? why does this ruler create too many copies and destroy them? What is the problem here?

Comment: Your "default constructor" is not a default constructor at all, that's quite misleading.

Comment: If you explain what copies you were expecting, we'll be much better equipped to explain your misunderstanding.

Comment: when you push your items on the vector temporary copies are made

Comment: @Quentin What do you mean by "Your constructor is not default etc."? How is it supposed to be? Can you give more details on it?

Comment: @FamZ i know but the order is interesting. Too many rulers are copied and destroyed.

Comment: @user2357112 Eventually when i push an item into the vector, i expect that it creates an copy and invokes the ctor. But the order is not as i predicted.

Comment: Are you aware that when the vector's backing buffer runs out of room, it needs to copy all elements into a new one? (Or move them, but you don't have a move constructor.)

Comment: you are pushing Pencil on the vector after you pushed Ruler, that means that a new vector is allocated with double of the previous size, that means that you need to copy the old vecor over to the new one, this is creating copies again

Comment: `this->name = new char [len];` should be `this->name = new char [len + 1];` - Or better still use `std::strring`

Comment: @user2357112 OMG! it creates a new buffer and deletes the old one o.O

Comment: @RıfatTolgaKiran a "default constructor" is a constructor with no parameter. It's the one that is called, for example, when constructing an automatic object with `Foo f;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that if a vector is full and you are pushing an element, the vector needs to resize. So when you push `Ruler` on the vector there's an array with a size of `sizeof(items)` created and the data is copied in(first copy constructor call for `Ruler`). Then you are pushing `Pencil` on the vector(first copy constructor call for `Pencil`), but the vector is out of memory, so a new array is allocated with double of the previous size `2 * sizeof(items)` and the old array is copied to the new array(second copy constructor call for `Ruler`) and the old array is destroyed(first destructor called for `Ruler` in old array) and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Your "default constructor" takes an argument and is, thus, not a default constructor in the C++ sense: default constructors can be called without any argument.

With respect to your question it seem the sequence is thus:

1. Initially the objects all get constructed.
2. There is a copy of the `Ruler` object inserting it into the `school` vector.
3. When `Pencil` is inserted this object is first copied but apparently there isn't enough space in the `school` vector: the `Pencil` object is copied into a newly allocated location and then `Ruler` is copied over and the original space is destroyed.
4. When `Book` is inserted the same sequence happens: the `Book` is copied into a new location and then `Ruler` and `Pencil` are copied there, too.
5. Finally, all the objects get destroyed.

The sequence is somewhat confusing in the sense that `std::vector` normally doesn't behave like that: it normally creates a small array right at the start which can accomodate more than one element. It seems, the implementation used starts off with a `capacity()` of just one and then doubles the capacity from there. You can verify this behavior by looking at `school.capacity()` between the calls to `school.push_back()`: whenever the `capacity()` increases, the underlying array gets increased.

Considering that your are allocating memory you may want to consider a move constructor which transfers the stored memory rather than allocating a new array to accomodate a copy to then just `delete` the original. The move constructor would look something like this:

```
items::items(items&& other)
    : name(other.name) {
    this->name = nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

std::vector manages its own memory. That means that std::vector only stores copies of an object, which means the object must have a meaningful copy constructor (and an assignment operator, but that's another issue).

When the destructor of a vector is invoked the memory held by the vector is released. std::vector also invokes an object's destructor when it is removed (through erase, pop_back, clear or the vector's destructor).